# How do I make repeated data show only once in inner join query Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I did an inner join in Postgres. I want the incoming json data to not contain repeated data. How can I update my query?

this query

```
SELECT academy_projects.project_name,
array_agg( academy_technology.name) as academy_technology,
array_agg( academy_users.user_name) as academy_users,
array_agg( academy_classes.name) as academy_classes,

FROM academy_projects
inner join academy_technology  on academy_technology.id=any(academy_projects.technology_id)
inner join academy_users  on academy_users.user_id = any(academy_projects.user_id)
inner join academy_classes  on academy_classes.id = any(academy_projects.classes_id)  
group by academy_projects.project_name
```

[image: database raw]

If the values ​​in the json data are the same, I want it to return only one, how should I edit my query?

for example academy_classes column  should be like this:

```
{insan,scooter}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DISTINCT: `array_agg( DISTINCT academy_technology.name)`